# Difference between *nameOfStruct and []nameOfStruct in Go (* and [])

Tags: go

I'm relatively new to GoLang,I have two method and all off method is access to struct, but i don't know what is difference about *ShipmentBaseModel and []ShipmentExpiredModel, why dont use [] all off them or this * ?

```
func (c *shipment) FindOneByGroupID(ctx context.Context, groupID string) (*ShipmentBaseModel, error) {
    span, ctx := tracer.StartSpanFromContext(ctx, "Repo: Shipment FindOneByGroupID")
    defer span.Finish()

    var output *ShipmentBaseModel
    rows, err := c.ps[shipmentFindOneByGroupID].Query(groupID)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return output, result.LoadOne(ctx, rows, &output)
}

func (c *shipment) FindAllShipmentPickupExpired(ctx context.Context) ([]ShipmentExpiredModel, error) {
    span, ctx := tracer.StartSpanFromContext(ctx, "Repo: Invoice FindAllShipmentPickupExpired")
    defer span.Finish()

    var output []ShipmentExpiredModel
    rows, err := c.ps[shipmentFindAllShipmentPickupExpired].Query(ShipmentTypePickup, AccountRoleCustomer, StatusCRRSRC, 100)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    _, err = result.LoadToStruct(ctx, rows, &output)

    return output, err
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*shipmentBaseModel is a `pointer` of shipmentBaseModel
and []shipmentBaseModel is a `slice` of shipmentBaseModel
if you want more definition about what is pointer and slice in Go i think you should go ahead to Go documentation and check em out
[slice](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7)
[pointer](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1)